# get response from childprocess and assert it

Tags: soapui, cucumberjs

I'm trying to execute my SOAPUI calls from cucumberjs. I have created a .bat file and running from childprocess. The problem i have here is, it executes but i don't see its output in the console(cmd). Also, i have to get the response status and assert it.

## Here is what i'm doing:

```
my page::

var apipage = function(){
    this.testapi = function(callback){
    console.log("..executing..");

     var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
      ls = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'my.bat']);

    ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    });

    ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('stderr: ' + data);
    });

    ls.on('exit', function (code) {
      console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
    });

module.exports = new apipage();

=================================================

spec file::

Then('rest must be executed' , function(callback){
apipage.testapi();
callback();
});

=============================================

output:

..executing..

1scenario(passed)
2 steps(passed)
```

========================

I want to capture the response status and assert it. Can someone help me with this please. The code works fine when i run as node program.

Comment: i removed the page file & added the function in spec file & could see the child process execution. But still unable to assert it with response status

Comment: looks like you need to figure async out first - make sure `callback` is called after `testapi` finished